# Make my Apache server serve my page with 200(from cache) NOT 304 or are there any public websites that will give a 200 (from cache) http response?

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf, http-status-codes

Just doing some research and

1. How to get my own local website to respond with a 200 (from cache), not a 304, but a 200 from cache
   so far in my httpd.conf i have 
   `Header unset ETag
   Header unset Last-Modified
   Header unset Cache-Control
   Header append Cache-Control "public"`

   But I'm not sure where to go from here, it's only responding with 200 ok.

OR

Show me a live, public website that will respond with a 200 (from cache) response. Any website that is safe for work is much appreciated.

Comment: The 304 code is Apache telling a client to display the clients cached version of a resource. It doesn't have to do with Apache serving from cache.

Comment: So regardless of my configuration, will the client always check against the server for Last-Modified before using a locally cached page?

Comment: That's what the client is supposed to do, yes. Some clients might not… Like older versions of Internet Explorer are hot and ready to use cache without checking against the server. I don't really understand your question or what you're trying to achieve, by the way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem is that I was examining in charles so obviously if it was pulling from my cache it wouldn't be seen in the proxy. If I pull from my local cache then I just need to examine the browsers response.   -- basically I need to receive a page that responded with 200 from cache to examine the javascript without using the server at all- completely on my browser (to look at performance.timing).